# Solve $\int_{0}^{t}\cos x\sin (t-x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convolution

I want to solve the following integral $$\int_{0}^{t}\cos x\sin (t-x)dx$$

What I tried to do is integration by parts twice, but it just brought me straight back to $$\int_{0}^{t}\cos x\sin (t-x)dx=\int_{0}^{t}\cos x\sin (t-x)dx$$ Not very informative indeed.

Is there any way to do this without resorting to trigonometric identities?

Comment: separate $\sin(t-x) = \sin(t)\cos(x) - \sin(x)\cos(t)$ and integrate.

Comment: Why the aversion to trig identities? I guess you could use complex exponential,  but that amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Actually I was wondering if it's possible to do it without trigonometric identities, since i do not remember them, and they will not be given to me on the day of the exam.

Comment: They aren't that difficult. Remember 
$$\sin(\alpha\pm\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta\pm\cos\alpha\sin\beta$$ and the rest of them follow naturally. Having the complex form at hand helps memorizing that as well.

Comment: There are a handful of trig identities that are broadly enough useful that they really are worth remembering. And you can generate those from an even smaller list of identities (as in a previous comment) if you must.

Comment: Is this your last math/science/engineering course ever?  If not, you will probably need to know some trig identities in the future anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x \mapsto t-x$ then

$\displaystyle I = \int_0^t \cos{x}\sin(t-x) \;{dx} = \int_0^t \sin{x}\cos(t-x) \;{dx} $

So $ \displaystyle  2I = \int_0^t [\cos{x}\sin(t-x)+\sin{x}\cos(t-x)]\;{dx}$

But $ \displaystyle \cos{x}\sin(t-x)+\sin{x}\cos(t-x)  = \sin(x+t-x) = \sin(t)$.

So $I \displaystyle = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \sin{x}\;{dx} = \frac{1}{2}(t\sin{t}).$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$\sin(t - x) \cos x = \frac{1}{2}\Big(\sin t + \sin (t - 2x)\Big)$$

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice symmetry trick. We have:
$$ I = \int_{-t/2}^{t/2}\cos(x+t/2)\sin(t/2-x)\,dx\\ = \int_{0}^{t/2}\left(\cos(t/2+x)\sin(t/2-x)+\cos(t/2-x)\sin(t/2+x)\right)\,dx\\ =\int_{0}^{t/2}\sin(t/2+x+t/2-x)\,dx\\=\int_{0}^{t/2}\sin t\,dx\\=\color{red}{\frac{t\sin t}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution is to use the trigonometric identities. Even though, if you really want to avoid those, here is a way :

Note that : $\displaystyle \sin(t-x) = \mathrm{Im} \Big( e^{i(t-x)} \Big) = \mathrm{Im} \Big( e^{it} e^{-ix} \Big)$. Therefore,

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{t} \cos(x) \sin(t-x) \, dx &= {} \mathrm{Im} \Bigg( \int_{0}^{t} \cos(x) e^{it} e^{-ix} \, dx \Bigg) \\[3mm]
 &= \mathrm{Im} \Bigg( e^{it} \int_{0}^{t} \cos(x) e^{-ix} \, dx \Bigg) \\
\end{align*}$$

But, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\displaystyle \cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$. As a consequence :

$$
\begin{align*}
e^{it} \int_{0}^{t} \cos(x) e^{-ix} \, dx &= {} e^{it} \int_{0}^{t} \Big( \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2} \Big) e^{-ix} \, dx \\[2mm] 
 &= e^{it} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{2} \, dx + e^{it} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{e^{-2ix}}{2} \, dx \\[2mm]
 &= \frac{te^{it}}{2} + \frac{1}{i} e^{it} \big( 1 - e^{-2it} \big) \\[2mm]
 &= \frac{te^{it}}{2} - ie^{it} + ie^{-it}. 
\end{align*}
$$

It follows that :

$$ \int_{0}^{t} \cos(x) \sin(t-x) \, dx = \frac{t\sin(t)}{2}. $$

Comment: Nice use of imaginary identities!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish to use trig, you could try solving the integral via Laplace transforms. In particular, the Laplace transform of your integral will look like the derivative of the transform of $\sin t$. Of course, this itself requires knowing Laplace identities... it's probably easier to just remember the basic trig identities.

Comment: I was gonna say, this has roots in convolution and Laplace integral transforms...

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align}
\int_0^t\cos\left(x\right)\sin\left(t-x\right)\:dx,\tag{1}
\end{align}
and since $\sin\left(t-x\right)=\sin\left(t\right)\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(t\right)$,we may re-write this integral as
\begin{align}
&\int_0^t \cos\left(x\right)\left[\sin\left(t\right)\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(t\right)\right]\:dx\tag{2}\\
&=\sin\left(t\right)\int_0^t \cos^2\left(x\right)\:dx-\cos\left(t\right)\int_0^t\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)\:dx,\tag{3}
\end{align}
and because of the reduction formula
\begin{align}
\int\cos^{n}\left(x\right)\:dx=\frac{\cos^{n-1}\left(x\right)\sin\left(x\right)}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\int\cos^{n-2}\left(x\right)\:dx,
\end{align}
we have
\begin{align}
&=\sin\left(t\right)\left[\frac{\cos\left(x\right)\sin\left(x\right)}{2}\bigg|_0^t+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\:dx\right]-\cos\left(t\right)\left[\frac{1}{2}\sin^2\left(x\right)\right]_0^t\tag{4}\\
&=\frac{\cos\left(t\right)\sin^2\left(t\right)}{2}+\frac{\sin\left(t\right)t}{2}-\frac{\cos\left(t\right)\sin^2\left(t\right)}{2}\tag{5}\\
&=\boxed{\frac{t\sin\left(t\right)}{2}.}\tag{6}
\end{align}

---

Another way to look at this problem is via convolution such that
\begin{align}
\left(f\ast g\right)\left(t\right)=\int_0^t f\left(t-x\right)g\left(x\right)\:dx,\tag{7}
\end{align}
and in this case our $f\left(t-x\right)=\sin\left(t-x\right)$ and $g\left(x\right)=\cos\left(x\right)$. Therefore, this is simply
\begin{align}
\sin\left(x\right)\ast\cos\left(x\right)=\cos\left(x\right)\ast\sin\left(x\right)=\int_0^t\sin\left(t-x\right)\cos\left(x\right)\:dx\\=\int_0^t \cos\left(t-x\right)\sin\left(x\right)\:dx.\tag{8}
\end{align}